# "void space" in a <li> with images

Tags: php, html, css, html-lists

I'm kind of stuck on this. I have to put an horizontal list of different states of some services I'm working on. I have 3 different states ( Green, Orange, Red ), and I want to "go back to the line" whenever the state changes. I have the feeling I need to write something like "you go xx pixels down" to correctly have my lists in order, but it still keeps packing weirdly. I don't really know if I'm clear.

Here's part of the code :

```
$brequest = 1;

        echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($arrstate as $sun){
        for($x=1 ; $x<4 ; $x++){
            if($sun[1] == $x){

                if($brequest != $x){
                    $brequest = $x;
                    echo "</ul><ul>\n"; //Note that it's just a try here
                }


                $affichage="&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=\"images/" . $images[$x] . ".svg\" title=\"" . $texte_alt[$x] . "\" alt=\"" . $texte_alt[$x] . "\" height=\"40px\" style=\"vertical-align:middle\"";
                $comment="<br /><br />".$sun[2]."<br /><br/>Last Updated : ".$sun[3]."<br /><br />By ".$sun[4]."</li>\n";

                echo "<li style=\"background-color: " . $couleur_etat[$x] . "\">" . $sun[0] . $affichage. $comment;


            }




        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

The array is sorted by states, and the `<style>` part is :

```
<style>
  ul { list-style-type: none;}
  li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 1em;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 15em;
    min-height: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

Feel free to ask me anything about the code. Thank you in advance for your answer !

Comment: We can't use PHP. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ...oh, and you can't use `display:inline` AND `float`. Pick one...not both.

Comment: You should not keep any space between one li end and other li start </li><li>. I guess you have "</li>\n" . and this /n might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to help.

I just had to clear:left every `<ul>` I use, this way the float will stop putting images at the same row. It goes like this :

```
echo "</ul><ul style=\"clear:left\">";
```

I know CSS in line is not that much appreciated, but I began HTML PHP & CSS Yesterday. So, let's run with it for the moment !

( And sorry for the bad example, I'll give more attention to details next time. Thank you ! )